# Cognito after logout then login, still get "logins don't match" error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have a logged in user, and I logout with:

```
cognitoUser.signOut();
```

Then I try to login as a different user.

An error is received that says "logins don't match".

How do I logout a user properly so this error doesn't happen upon the first new login attempt?

Answer (score 2):

Your CognitoAWSCredentials should have a method called `clear()`. You need to call this before you try to login with a different user. Seems that something gets cached.

Comment: `CognitoAWSCredentials` seems to not exist anywhere in my login / logout code. Also `AWS.CognitoAWSCredentials` does not seem to exist in the code. Are you sure that's what I should use to clear the current user?

Comment: I think he was confused about your SDK, it looks like you're using Android? Try calling clear() on the credentials provider, that'll wipe credentials and logins and all that fun stuff. Calling signOut() on the user is totally valid, it's just that they're two separate services that don't necessarily know what the other is doing. Both are needed.

Answer (score 0):

If for people like me who have tried the `clear()` on the credentialsprovider and calling the `signOut()` on the user, and still getting the error as logins don't match, it should be the reason because the CognitoSyncManager is retaining the identity and other credentials of the previous logged in user. To overcome this, the call to `wipeData()` on the cognitosyncmanager client has to be made when the logout is initiated, this will make sure that all the retained data are removed.